# Rails 4 - How to properly set up a validation action on the controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have LDAP authentication through Devise, and before I create an user on the database (with the additional information due to business rules involved on the User), I'd like to collect some other information present on the company's servers.

I have a `user_query` action so that I can display the following modal:

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h3>Find User by Email</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <% flash.each do |name, msg| -%>
          <%= content_tag :div, msg, class: name %>
      <% end -%>
      <%= form_tag('/users/new', method: :get, remote: true) do -%>
          <%= text_field_tag 'user_email', nil, placeholder: 'Insert user email', class: 'form-control' %>
          <%= submit_tag 'Get user information', remote: true, class: 'btn btn-default' %>
      <% end -%>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It has a text box where the user inputs the email to query the server  and check whether that user exists, if it does, redirect to the `new` User action, sending the found user information, else, I'd like it to display an error stating that the informed user email could not be found.

The action I created to do this validation after the user has informed the `email`, is the `authenticate_user_email`, as follows:

```
def authenticate_user_email
  respond_to do |format|
    if authenticated_user = Devise::LDAP::Adapter.get_ldap_entry(params[:user_email])
      format.html { redirect_to action: :new, authenticated_user: authenticated_user }
    else
      format.json { render json: 'User email not found', status: :not_found }
    end
  end
end
```

However, I could not get this to work setting the `authenticate_user_email` as a `after_action` of `user_query`, nor do I know if this is the correct approach to do so, which is why I ask, what is the correct way to set up this validation (keeping in mind that every action is rendered within a modal)?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at [Active Record Validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/active_record_validations.html)?

Comment: Yes, but aren't AR Validations meant validate data before saving it to the database? On this case it wouldn't be actually saving data, more like a step to validate that the user exists on the company, and then enable it to gain additional information on the application-side (or not).

Answer (score 0):

Change the `if` condition in `authenticate_user_email` method from

`authenticated_user = Devise::LDAP::Adapter.get_ldap_entry(params[:user_email])`

to

`authenticated_user == Devise::LDAP::Adapter.get_ldap_entry(params[:user_email])`

Also , have a look at [Active Record Validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/active_record_validations.html) as @lurker suggested

Comment: The condition isn't validating whether the `authenticated_user` is equal to the user found (or not) by the `LDAP::Adapter`, but checking if the user was found by the `LDAP::Adapter`, at the same time that it assigns the result to the variable `authenticated_user`.